# how do you remove the "Search Your Computer" icon from launcher in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, launcher, icons

Is there a set of commands that can be entered to remove the "Search Your Computer" icon from the launcher in Ubuntu 16.04? It does not let you just unlock from launcher like other icons in the launcher

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the main Ubuntu logo icon from the launcher.

Answer (score -2):

It is the Dashboard Icon. It is the fast and easiest way to finding applications installed and other useful items. Pressing the Windows Key will open it (aka SUPER key in forum answers), to close without mouse, hit ESC. As the poster above me said, it can't be removed.